# Disable mouse events on overlapping divs without pointer-events

Tags: javascript, css, html, cross-browser

I have a `div` with a `onClick` event, but it's not detecting the mouse because of an overlapping `div`. I can't put it below the 1<sup>st</sup> one, so changing the `z-index` isn't an option.

Is there any way to disable the mouse events on the 2<sup>nd</sup> `div` without the pointer-events? I need this to be cross-browser.

Requested sample. Right now all the event does is fire an alert:

```
<div class="buttonDiv" onClick="buttonAction()"></div>
<div class="filterDiv"></div>
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your HTML?

Comment: There really isn't much to it. It's just one div after the other. But I'll post the sample if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find was having a Mouse Move event attached to the canvas and compare the coordinates of the button to the position and dimensions of the buttons. It's a pain, but at least it does the job

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

HTML

```
<div class="buttonDiv" onClick="buttonAction(event)">
  OUTER
  <div class="filterDiv">INNER</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var buttonAction = function(e) {
  if(e.target.className == "buttonDiv") {
    //code here
    alert('got here');
  }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aFRcd/1/

Basically on the click, you send along the click `event` and then you can see which div was actually clicked using `event.target`

You'll notice in the example that clicking on OUTER fires the alert whereas INNER does not.

Comment: Sorry but I can't place the 2nd div inside the 1st. This code I'm testing is part of a larger program that demands them to be in that order

Comment: I don't understand.. where are the closing div tags in the sample you posted?

Comment: Forgot to add them in my hurry to write. Fixed it

Comment: @Catpixels this would appear to work whether or not the `<div>`s are nested'

Comment: how are the divs overlapping? are they absolutely positioned with z-indexes or something?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd has to be above the first (and visible) at all times. It's part of the rules given to me